# joomla 1.7 - how to create rss feed for my content?

Tags: joomla, rss, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

is it possible to create the feed for joomla website? what is the way??
the joomla doc page dont hv the related page yet
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_component_feeds

what i mean is **creating the rss** using the contents of my joomla webiste but **not displaying** other's rss feed in my joomla website

i saw that joomla administration panel have something call rss content, but it is only used for displaying rss feed, but not creating , am i right?
thx

Answer (score 5):

This will work for Joomla 1.6, Joomla 1.7, and Joomla 2.5

RSS feeds are only available for the following:

-- A Category

-- Featured Articles

**CATEGORY FEED**

In the Joomla Admin you can get any category ID in the Category Manager, you can construct the feed url yourself even if it has no menu item on your website:

```
RSS:
http://YOUR_SITE/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=YOUR_CATEGORY ID&format=feed&type=rss
ATOM:
http://YOUR_SITE/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=YOUR_CATEGORY ID&format=feed&type=atom
```

**FEATURED ARTICLE FEED**

```
RSS:
http://YOUR_SITE/index.php?option=com_content&view=featured&format=feed&type=rss
ATOM:
http://YOUR_SITE/index.php?option=com_content&view=featured&format=feed&type=atom
```

**MAKING A FEED FROM A CATEGORY BLOG MENU ITEM USING SEF LINKS**

You can also simply navigate to a category blog or featured blog menu item that is already  created and has friendly URL's which show just the SEF alias' copy it and add `?format=feed&type=rss` or `?format=feed&type=atom`. Here is an example:

```
http://YOUR_SITE/ALIAS/?format=feed&type=rss
http://YOUR_SITE/ALIAS/?format=feed&type=atom
```

**FULL TEXT OR INTRO TEXT?**

In each menu item configuration you have "Integration Options" in the right panel that allow you to decide if you want that item to show the full text or just the intro text as well as show/hide the "read More.." link.

Also, you can set a global setting for Full/Intor text from the Article Manager. In the admin, simply navigate to the Article Manager and click on the "Options" icon in the upper right of the screen and go to the "Integration" tab.

Comment: It has been suggested that this will work in Joomla 3 as well, and I am sure it will work for your SEF links, but I know some things changed if you are not using SEF, so hopefully some folks let me know if it does work using SEF. I think the feeds available in J3 are different. If someone knows, comment here and I will update the answer. I have not been using Joomla lately.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to have an RSS feed from your articles in your Joomla installation, that is done automatically for you. Joomla generates a RSS feed for every menu item that links to a category and for the items with the menu item type "frontpage" (or "featured" in case of Joomla 1.6/1.7) The link to the RSS feed is already in the header of those pages and can be used directly. If you developed your own component, you have to write your own RSS view for that component. I'd say the best way would be to look at the RSS view of com_content for that.

Answer (score 1):

Bij default the RSS syndication creates a master category, you can find in your category manager.

What i did: create a menu, give it one item: a category blog and then choose RSS as category. Publish this menu with a menu module.

Then click the rss menu item and you will retrieve the rssfeed url, and then go back to module manager and give yor module a non existing position like yagrooble or whatever.

Your RSS is hidden but the link still works!